QGIS Server equivalent of QGIS custom environment variables (AZURE_STORAGE...)- Connect Azure blob storage images to Lizmap
Im trying to use COG geotiffs stored in Azure Blob storage in Lizmap, served via QGIS server/Apache
In QGIS (desktop), you set custom environment variables for AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY with their respective values, then connect and add the data. This is working fine on QGIS desktop and I can load the geotiffs.
What is the equivalent way to store those variables so that I can add these geotiffs to Lizmap?
I've tried adding them to the lizmap-fcgi.conf file (i.e. FcgidInitialEnv AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT somevalue) but that didn't seem to work
Would it be a case of using a QGIS server environment variable QGIS_OPTIONS_PATH (outlined here: QGIS documentation, then setting up those variables in their own .ini file?
